# Permission issues in cloudSQL SQL Server (GCP)

Tags: sql-server, user-permissions, google-cloud-sql

I see permission error when i tried to shrink files/db in CloudSQL sql server.

I know its a managed service and do not have sa user and super privileges.

But is there any similar user like sa (or) alternate ways to carry out such tasks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrbCG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i just figured it out, we are able to enable the sa user with the default sqlserver superuser login and then grant sysadmin to the desired user accounts.

[sa user enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok65p.png)

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/users

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

I think we need the necessary access for performing cloudsql operations, which could be obtained from IAM similar to below,

- Cloud SQL Admin
- Cloud SQL Client
- Cloud SQL Editor
- Cloud SQL Viewer

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-sql-roles

Comment: Hello Kiran, Following the steps you described were you able to shrink your db already? 

All users you create using Cloud SQL are created as part of the **cloudsqlsuperuser** role. The [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/users) is pretty straightforward on that - your users will not have the **SUPERUSER** or **REPLICATION** attributes.

Comment: I agree, but enabling sa user we can grant the required and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not be possible to do it on your own.

In order to perform shrink operations on your db you will need to contact the [**GCP support**](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

> select suser_name()
> ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
>
> ---
>
> sqlserver 
> Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

@Dothertechie can you please clarify how exactly did you enable sa? Or did they just fix the loophole?